# PHP Calling a class function from within a anonymous function

Tags: php

How do I call the doSomethingElse function from within this anonymous function?

If I try $this->doSomethingElse() I get 'Using $this when not in object context ' error

```
class MyController extends AppController {

    public function doSomethingElse()
    {
        //do something
    }


    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->Crud->on('afterSave', function(CakeEvent $event) {
            if ($event->subject->success) {

                    //how do I call 'doSomethingElse' from here

            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not valid code, it's unclear what you're asking exactly.

Comment: sorry, copied code incorrectly

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a reference to your `MyController` outside your anonymous function and use this like

```
class MyController extends AppController {

    public function doSomethingElse()
    {
        //do something
    }


    public function doSomething()
    {
        $reference = $this;

        $this->Crud->on('afterSave', function(CakeEvent $event) use ($reference) {
            if ($event->subject->success) {

                    //how do I call 'doSomethingElse' from here
                    $reference->doSomethingElse();

            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

After PHP5.4 `$this` can be used in anonymous functions instead pass it as a reference in `use (...)`.

Learn more about anonymous functions in [php site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)